# C++ how to declare a vector of objects as a member of a class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to declare a `vector<Item>` as a private member of another class `Inventory`, but it is giving me an error saying that `Item` is not in scope. Both classes are declared in the same file. I don't know how to change the scope that it looks at or whatever you are supposed to do to make it work.

Here is the code to make absolutely clear what I'm trying to do.

```
class Inventory {
public:

private:
    vector<Item> inventory;
};

class Item {
public:
    void SetName(string nm)
        { name = nm; };
    void SetQuantity(int qnty)
        { quantity = qnty; };
    void SetPrice(int pric)
        { price = pric; };
    virtual void Print()
        { cout << name << " " << quantity << " for $" << price 
          << endl; };
    virtual ~Item()
        { return; };
protected:
    string name;
    int quantity;
    int price;
};
```

Comment: Put the declaration of Item before that of Inventory.

Comment: You need to define `Item` *before* you use it as the `vector` argument.

Comment: Thanks I honestly don't think I would have figured that out anytime soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Item` must be defined before its usage as a template argument.

Technically, you may be able to get away with a forward declaration in specific contexts, but to save you time and frustration with learning the exact rules, it is easier to just make sure you have defined it first.

In general, the order of declarations are important. If you **use** a type in the declaration of another type, the used type must **already** be defined. Exceptions to this rule involve usage by pointer and reference which only require forward declaration.

Comment: As a rule of thumb for whether a forward declaration will work, I ask myself whether the compiler needs to know the size or layout of the object e.g. to reserve space within another class layout. If not then there's a good chance forward declaration is OK. In this case a vector probably doesn't need to know the layout of an element until you try to add or access it. A quick test showed a forward declaration working on at least one compiler.

Comment: @MarkRansom is correct. I was going to add some details to my answer in terms of `sizeof`, but he's essentially done that. I wasn't sure whether `std::vector` needed a full definition or just a forward declaration and couldn't verify at the time, but in general, it will depend on the exact template definition in question whether or not it is needed at the time of the template argument use. For instance `boost::shared_ptr` specifically says they *do not* need a full definition, but `std::auto_ptr` does.

Answer (score 2):

As `std::vector<Item>` is a type in its own right, it must be declared after the *declaration* of the `Item` class.

(It's similar to the rule that for `class Child : public Base`, the declaration of `Base` needs to appear above that line).

A *forward declaration* is **not** insufficient.

One way round this is to use a `std::vector<std::shared<Item>>` (a vector of smart pointers) but that, of course, changes the structure of the vector. In that case a forward declaration *is* sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Define Item first, then Inventory.

```
class Item {

public:
    void SetName(string nm)
        { name = nm; };
    void SetQuantity(int qnty)
        { quantity = qnty; };
    void SetPrice(int pric)
        { price = pric; };
    virtual void Print()
        { cout << name << " " << quantity << " for $" << price 
          << endl; };
    virtual ~Item()
        { return; };
protected:
    string name;
    int quantity;
    int price;
};

class Inventory {
public:

private:
    vector<Item> inventory;
};
```